# How to upload file to specific folder in destination server using curl?

Tags: curl

I have to upload file to specific folder on destination server. How do I pass a folder name as parameter in `curl` command?

```
curl -vvv -F "upload_filename=@/Users/example/test"-L http://example.server.com:8080/
```

Comment: This questions makes no sense because `curl` has nothing to do with what folder the destination server chooses to store. Perhaps you don't understand what curl does.

Comment: Why don't you use `scp`?

Comment: Does the server have a FTP server too? In that case you could use `curl -T localfile ftp://ftp.example.com/dir/path/`. Reference: https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl/usingcurl-ftp/ftp-advanced#uploading-with-ftp

Answer (score 2):

You can't upload to a specific folder on a webserver. If it were a ftp server this would work, but this is a completely different story.

The receiving end on the server (the code that lies behind your root directory, perhaps a index.php or something like this) is in charge of deciding where to put the data it gets.

By using the curl command you provide you will *read* from the file you specify and post that files content to a webserver.